# Generate a PDF file from two gridviews using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, gridview, itext

I use to generate a PDF file from a gridview using **iTextSharp**.

I need a help because I am not familiar with iTextSharp.

I'm using two gridviews in my aspx page: **gvProducts** and **gvUsers**.

The generation a PDF file from a single (**gvProducts**) gridview using iTextSharp working correctly.

I can't print the first and second GridView in the same PDF.

This is what I want:

1. Open PDF document;
2. Print result of my first GridView;
3. Print result of my second GridView;
4. Close, Save and download PDF document in the client.

Anybody know how can I do that?

Thank you in advance.

My code below.

```
protected void ExportToPDFWithFormatting()
{
    //link button column is excluded from the list
    int colCount = gvProducts.Columns.Count - 1;

    //Create a table
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(colCount);

    table.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    table.WidthPercentage = 100;

    //create an array to store column widths
    int[] colWidths = new int[gvProducts.Columns.Count];

    PdfPCell cell;
    string cellText;

    //create the header row
    for (int colIndex = 0; colIndex < colCount; colIndex++)
    {

        table.SetWidths(new int[] { 0, 40, 120, 110, 60, 60, 100, 90, 100, 50, 50, 50, 40, 30, 260, 200, 0 });

        //fetch the header text
        cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(gvProducts.HeaderRow.Cells[colIndex].Text);

        //create a new cell with header text
        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont(
                                BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                                BaseFont.CP1252,
                                BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
                                false);

        iTextSharp.text.Font font = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText.Replace("<br />", Environment.NewLine), font));
        cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        cell.FixedHeight = 45f;

        //set the background color for the header cell
        cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#a52a2a"));

        //add the cell to the table. we dont need to create a row and add cells to the row
        //since we set the column count of the table to 4, it will automatically create row for
        //every 4 cells
        table.AddCell(cell);
    }


    //export rows from GridView to table
    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < gvProducts.Rows.Count; rowIndex++)
    {
        if (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gvProducts.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                //fetch the column value of the current row
                cellText = Server.HtmlDecode(gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[j].Text);

                //create a new cell with column value
                cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, FontFactory.GetFont("PrepareForExport", 8)));                   
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                cell.FixedHeight = 25f;

                //Set Color of Alternating row
                if (rowIndex % 2 != 0)
                {
                    cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f5f5dc"));
                }
                else
                {
                    cell.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#fcfcfc"));
                }


                //add the cell to the table
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }
        }
    }

    //Create the PDF Document
    Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A3.Rotate(), 30f, 30f, 30f, 0f);

    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);

    //open the stream
    pdfDoc.Open();
    table.HeaderRows = 1;
    iTextSharp.text.Font fdefault = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE);
    string s = "Report";
    pdfDoc.Add(new Paragraph(s, fdefault));

    //add the table to the document
    pdfDoc.Add(table);

    //close the document stream
    pdfDoc.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + DateTime.Now + ".pdf");
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.End();
}
```

**Edit #1**

This is my code for generate pdf on GridView number two (**gvUsers**).

The code working but in the headers columns I have the names of GridView number one (**gvProducts**)... why?

```
    //start pdf gridview number two
    int colCountUsers = gvUsers.Columns.Count - 1;
    PdfPTable tableUsers = new PdfPTable(colCountUsers);
    tableUsers.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
    tableUsers.WidthPercentage = 100;
    int[] colWidthsUsers = new int[gvUsers.Columns.Count];
    PdfPCell cellUsers;
    string cellTextUsers;
    for (int colIndexUsers = 0; colIndexUsers < colCountUsers; colIndexUsers++)
    {
        tableUsers.SetWidths(new int[] { 0, 40, 120, 110, 60, 60, 100 });
        cellTextUsers = Server.HtmlDecode(gvProducts.HeaderRow.Cells[colIndexUsers].Text);
        BaseFont bfUsers = BaseFont.CreateFont(
                                BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                                BaseFont.CP1252,
                                BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
                                false);

        iTextSharp.text.Font fontUsers = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfUsers, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
        cellUsers = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellTextUsers.Replace("<br />", Environment.NewLine), fontUsers));
        cellUsers.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        cellUsers.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        cellUsers.FixedHeight = 45f;
        cellUsers.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#a52a2a"));
        tableUsers.AddCell(cellUsers);
    }


    for (int rowIndexUsers = 0; rowIndexUsers < gvUsers.Rows.Count; rowIndexUsers++)
    {
        if (gvUsers.Rows[rowIndexUsers].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < gvUsers.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                cellTextUsers = Server.HtmlDecode(gvUsers.Rows[rowIndexUsers].Cells[j].Text);
                cellUsers = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellTextUsers, FontFactory.GetFont("PrepareForExport", 8)));
                cellUsers.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
                cellUsers.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                cellUsers.FixedHeight = 25f;
                tableUsers.AddCell(cellUsers);
            }
        }
    }

    Document pdfDocUsers = new Document(PageSize.A3.Rotate(), 30f, 30f, 30f, 0f);
    PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDocUsers, Response.OutputStream);
    pdfDocUsers.Open();
    tableUsers.HeaderRows = 1;
    iTextSharp.text.Font fdefaultUsers = FontFactory.GetFont("Verdana", 18, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLUE);
    string sUsers = "Users";
    pdfDocUsers.Add(new Paragraph(sUsers, fdefaultUsers));
    pdfDocUsers.Add(tableUsers);
    pdfDocUsers.Close();
    //end pdf gridview number two



    //in first pdf gridview
    //add the table to the document
    pdfDoc.Add(table);
    pdfDoc.Add(tableUsers);
```

Comment: Can you just create another `PdfPTable tableUsers` and do the similar manipulations with it and gvUsers, and then where you add first table to the pdf document `pdfDoc.Add(table);` also call `pdfDoc.Add(tableUsers);`.

Comment: I'm with @myroman, just do it twice. You say it doesn't work but you don't have the second block of code so we can't tell you why. I can tell you, however, to get rid of `Response.Write(pdfDoc)`. That line of code doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: I'm confused, you've got two instance of the `Document` class, `pdfDocUsers` and `pdfDoc`, so you're making two separate and unrelated PDFs. Is that right and is that what you're intending?

Comment: Not I need one only file pdf with the dates of two gridviews-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int colCount1 = gvProducts1.Columns.Count - 1;

//Create a table
PdfPTable table1 = new PdfPTable(colCount1);

table1.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
table1.WidthPercentage = 100;

//create an array to store column widths
int[] colWidths1 = new int[gvProducts1.Columns.Count];

PdfPCell cell1;
string cellText1;

//create the header row
for (int colIndex1 = 0; colIndex1 < colCount1; colIndex1++)
{

    table1.SetWidths(new int[] { 0, 40, 120, 110, 60, 60, 100, 90, 100, 50, 50, 50, 40, 30, 260, 200, 0 });

    //fetch the header text
    cellText1 = Server.HtmlDecode(gvProducts1.HeaderRow.Cells[colIndex1].Text);

    //create a new cell with header text
    BaseFont bf1 = BaseFont.CreateFont(
                            BaseFont.HELVETICA,
                            BaseFont.CP1252,
                            BaseFont.EMBEDDED,
                            false);

    iTextSharp.text.Font font1 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD, BaseColor.WHITE);
    cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText.Replace("<br />", Environment.NewLine), font));
    cell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
    cell1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    cell1.FixedHeight = 45f;

    //set the background color for the header cell
    cell1.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#a52a2a"));

    //add the cell to the table. we dont need to create a row and add cells to the row
    //since we set the column count of the table to 4, it will automatically create row for
    //every 4 cells
    table1.AddCell(cell1);
}


//export rows from GridView to table
for (int rowIndex1 = 0; rowIndex1 < gvProducts1.Rows.Count; rowIndex1++)
{
    if (gvProducts.Rows[rowIndex1].RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        for (int j1 = 0; j1 < gvProducts1.Columns.Count - 1; j1++)
        {
            //fetch the column value of the current row
            cellText1 = Server.HtmlDecode(gvProducts1.Rows[rowIndex1].Cells[j].Text);

            //create a new cell with column value
            cell1 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText1, FontFactory.GetFont("PrepareForExport", 8)));                   
            cell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
            cell1.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
            cell1.FixedHeight = 25f;

            //Set Color of Alternating row
            if (rowIndex1 % 2 != 0)
            {
                cell1.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#f5f5dc"));
            }
            else
            {
                cell1.BackgroundColor = new BaseColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#fcfcfc"));
            }


            //add the cell to the table
            table1.AddCell(cell1);
        }
    }
}

//Create the PDF Document

//open the stream


//add the table to the document
pdfDoc.Add(table1);

//close the document stream
pdfDoc.Close();

Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;" + DateTime.Now + ".pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your answer... your code export two gridviews in pdf file?

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq 1) I had used two tables for generate pdf. 2)then fetching heading of column using gridview. 3)Then filling column using [row][column] number of table. 4)than just add it with doc.add(filledtablename)......you will find both gridview result in pdf

Comment: @AntonioMailtraq Please explain had you written any code for second gridview to table in your code i am not able to find it anywhere....after arranging above code i think your problem will solved